# How to change the font color of all the values from UL using inline css?

Tags: html, css

Following is the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class='top'>HRS</span>
    <br />
    <span class='dgt'>"+hours+"</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <br />
    <span class='devd'>:</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='top'>MINS</span>
    <br />
    <span class='dgt'>"+minutes+"</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <br />
    <span class='devd'>:</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='top'>SEC</span>
    <br />
    <span class='dgt'>"+seconds+"</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class='clear'></div>";
```

I want to change the font color to red of every thing between all the `<span></span>` using inline css. Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to use inline styles? If that's what you really have to do, you can do this using the `style` attribute:

```
<li>
    <span class='top' style="color: red">SEC</span>
    <br />
    <span class='dgt' style="color: red">"+seconds+"</span>
</li>
```

Alternatively, why not just target them using CSS (externally):

```
ul li span {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using span for all li,so you can use `inline` css for `ul`  `<ul style='color:red;'>`

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/2yaqx/)**

```
  <ul style='color:red;'>
      <li>
        <span class='top'>HRS</span>
        <br />
        <span class='dgt'>"+hours+"</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <br />
        <span class='devd'>:</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class='top'>MINS</span>
        <br />
        <span class='dgt'>"+minutes+"</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <br />
        <span class='devd'>:</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class='top'>SEC</span>
        <br />
        <span class='dgt'>"+seconds+"</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class='clear'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed right and you wanted to color everything between the `:`.
Just use `style='color:red;'` as an attribute for the tags you want to color red.

E.g:

```
<span class='dgt' style='color:red;'>"+seconds+"</span>
```